# Adding a table row in Titanium from a JSON Object

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator

I'm building an app with Titanium and I'm trying to generate a list of cars from a JSON object but I don't seem to be getting any results. When I log the variable inside the loop I'm getting 'undefined'. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
var cars = [
    {title: 'VW Golf', pricePerHour: '6€'},
    {title: 'Peugeot 206', pricePerHour: '5€'},
    {title: 'Renault Clio', pricePerHour: '6,50€'}
];

var tableData = [];

var tableView = Titanium.UI.createTableView();

for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {

    var tR = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        title: cars.title,
        height: 100
    });
    tableData.push(tR);
}
tableView.setData(tableData);
main.add(tableView);
main.open();
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see your debug statement inside the loop.  However you are attempting to reference cars.title in your row title, and this would be undefined.  cars[i].title will be the reference to the title field of the current object in the loop.